# Press search return result slow

Tags: search-results, performance, topology

We are using SP2013 standard on-premise. The farm have about 40,000 index items and concurrent less than 100 users. Incremental crawl is scheduled every 15min and full crawl every weekend.

The problem is whenever user type something and press "search", the result page return slowly. Roughly 5sec. However, once the site collection being warmed up for search, the next attempt for different keyword would be faster (around 1-2sec)

We are planning to scale up our farm by adding more VM servers. Existing there are 2WFE, 2APP, 2OWA and 1SQL server. SQL server is 128GB ram while all other servers has 8GB ram + 2x2cores cpu.

In order to solve the search slow issue, which area should be scaled up?

1. Add more WFE servers?
2. Add more resources (ram and Cpu) to WFE?
3. Add more APP server and dedicate for crawling component?
4. Add a WFE server dedicated for crawling purpose (only crawler can visit this server)
5. Maybe I just need a good warmup script?

Many thanks.

Comment: How many servers do you have and what specs do they have ( Ram & Cpu )?

Comment: I guess you could start with adding 4 gig to all the other servers, making them 12 GB ram as that are what Microsoft recommends as a minimum for servers in a three tier farm or larger and see if that make's any change.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396